# Error "Too many levels of symbolic links"

Tags: linux

Estoy tratando de instalar linux en mi Chromebook en una tajeta SD con crouton.
Al ejecutar el comando

```
$ sudo crouton -t gnome,gnome-desktop,core,xorg,audio,keyboard,x11 -p /media/removable/SDCARD`
```

Obtengo este error:

> cp: failed to access '/media/removable/SDCARD/bin/delete-chroot': Too many levels of symbolic link

Intente resolverlo de esta manera:

```
chronos@localhost /usr/local/bin $ sudo ln -s  /media/removable/SDCARD/bin/delete-chroot
```

Pero sigue dando el mismo error, tambien he intentado con este:

```
chronos@localhost /usr/local $ sudo ln -s /media/removable/SDCARD/chroots
```

Pero obtengo el mismo error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Respuesta corta

Estás usando mal `ln -s`.

Primero borra ese enlace simbólico problemático (antes asegúrate de que ese sea el archivo que quieras borrar) con `rm`.

Después utiliza adecuadamente:

```
$ ln -s <ruta del archivo o folder existente> <ruta que quieres que tenga ese nombre como referencia al archivo>
```

## Respuesta larga

Un enlace simbólico es un archivo que es tan sólo un nombre en el sistema de archivos, es decir, es un archivo que tan sólo una referencia a otro archivo.

Si te aparece ese error, es porque el enlace simbólico se tiene a si mismo como nombre. Es como si le preguntaras a alguien "¿Quién eres?", y te respondiera "Yo". Simplemente le gritas (porque es la salida del error estandard) "¡Too many levels of symbolic links!", porque entonces "Yo soy yo y yo soy yo, etc".

Por ejemplo, supón que creamos un archivo de la forma:

```
$ echo "hola" > archivo_original
```

Luego creamos un enlace simbólico (o enlace "suave" por *soft link*):

```
$ ln -sv ./archivo_original ./enlace_simbolico
'./enlace_simbolico' -> './archivo_original'
```

Donde `ln` es un comando que nos ayuda a crear enlaces ("duros" o "suaves"), y el parámetro `-s` le indica que cree los suaves.

La forma de utilizarlo (específicamente para enlaces suaves) es:

```
 ln -s <ruta del objetivo> <ruta del enlace>
```

Si vemos qué hay dentro del directorio donde usamos la pruebas, tenemos:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 cuau cuau  5 Dec 13 21:26 archivo_original
lrwxrwxrwx 1 cuau cuau 18 Dec 13 21:28 enlace_simbolico -> ./archivo_original
```

Y si vemos lo que hay dentro de ambos archivos, tenemos que es lo mismo:

```
$ head *
==> archivo_original <==
hola

==> enlace_simbolico <==
hola
```

### Reproduciendo el error

Si utilizamos el nombre del archivo como nombre y como objetivo:

```
 $ ln -sv ./enlace_simbolico ./enlace_simbolico
```

Y aplicamos el comando `head` anterior:

```
$ head *
==> archivo_original <==
hola
head: cannot open 'enlace_simbolico' for reading: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

Y replicamos el error que tienes.

### Nota

Es importante ver que al usar `ln` utilizamos rutas enteras o uno que otro alias:

```
$ ln -s /ruta/a/comando1 /ruta/a/enlace_de_comando1
$ ln -s ./ruta/a/comando1 ./ruta/a/comando1
$ ln -s $PWD/<etc> <etc>
```

Comment: Muchicimas gracias por tu ayuda, ya utilice el comando correctamente aunque sigo obteniendo un error parecido   "chroot: failed to run command '/prepare.sh': Too many levels of symbolic links"

Comment: Entonces el enlace simbolico fallido es el del archivo `/prepare.sh`. Aplica la respuesta que te di con ese archivo.

Comment: Y si te vuelve a aparecer en la vida un error que diga "Too many levels of ..." en otros archivo; entonces vuelve a aplicar mi respuesta. O mejor lee el manual de tu programa con más calma.